# JSF Primefaces Datatable ActionLink problems

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Prerequisites:

- Glasfish 3.1
- JSF 2.1
- Primefaces 5.2

---

User Story:

I want to implement a delete row function on my Primefaces DataTable, the Delete Function has to be displayed within the table.

---

Implementation:

datatable header

```
<p:dataTable value="#{a.list}" var="var">
```

delete

```
<p:column headerText="Delete">
    <p:commandLink value="-" action="#{a.delete(var)}" />
</p:column>
```

delete method in bean

```
public void delete(Something sth) {

    model.getList().remove(sth);        
}
```

---

Outcome:

[image: Outcome]

When hovering over the commandLink its showing me this Uniform Resource Locator  localhost/applicationname/#

Eclipse is giving me the Facelet Validator Warning Marker Syntax Error on this ExpressionLanguage Code `#{a.delete(var)}`

---

Question:

What am i missing in order to delete the row?

Comment: What was/is the scope of your bean? If it was request scoped, that explaines why it did not work with the pf button and does with the plain jsf one. By that change, you switched from using ajax to a non ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I have changed to commandlink from JSF (not primefaces) and got the Error, that my method shouldnt be void, but String after changing that and returning null it works...

```
public String delete(Something sth) {

    model.getList().remove(sth); return null; 
}
```

Comment: because the action return a string for a navigation case and actionListener only process a method.